# Sharing data value between functions in C

Tags: c

I have a simple structure in dbinfo.h viz.

```
typedef struct {
   int fields;
} dbinfo;
```

In the main program I have:

```
#include <string.h>
 ...
#include "dbinfo.h"
extern dbinfo *tst_info;

void main() {

tst_info = (dbinfo *) calloc(1, sizeof(dbinfo));

dbinfo.fields = 3;

printf("\n number of fields = %d"), getnumflds());
...
}
```

In another file utilities.c I have

```
#include "dbinfo.h"
extern dbinfo *tst_info;

int getnumflds() {

   return tst_info.fields;
}
```

When I try to link I get undefined symbols in utilities.c of tst_info.
If I remove the extern then I get no unresolved symbols, but the value of fields is 0.

What am i doing wrong here?

I simply want to be able to use and change the value of 'fields' that was set in main in other functions compiled separately.

Been a long time since I used C and having trouble accessing those neurons!

Comment: Exactly, to tell a bit more. Extern just tells "the variable is elsewere compiler, trust me." But you never actually make it, so the linker does not find it.
Just remove the extern from one of the files.

Comment: Don't understand.  In the main program, I specify it is extern and alloc it.

Comment: When I remove the extern from the main program, and reference 'fields' in the subroutine it is zero even though I set it to 3 in the main program.

Comment: Don't abuse extern variables. All data needed in a function should be passed to it as arguments.

Comment: It looks to me like you never actually _define_ the symbol anywhere, meaning that it has no address allocated within your program, and so accessing it becomes pure UB. The particular results you observe are then just happenstance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All definitions of tst_info must be `extern` **except one**.  The `extern` keyword on a variable in a certain object file tells the linker to refrain from allocating space for it in the data segment, because storage for the variable will be provided in some other object file.  If all object files define the variable as `extern`, then there is no object file that provides storage for it.

You can read more about this than you can handle in this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1433387/773113

Comment: Detail: "must be extern except one" slightly over-states. `extern int foo;
int foo;
int foo = 5;` is valid as `int foo;` is a tentative definition.

Comment: @chux true, but I am not sure how I could avoid over-stating and at the same time refrain from suggesting a practice which is non-portable and therefore un-advisable.

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring `tst_info` as `extern` in both translation units. The `extern` keyword means it’s available elsewhere, in some `extern`al translation unite. Somewhere, you need to actually define it by *not* having the `extern` keyword and instead setting an initial value (which can be the result of `calloc`, or `NULL`, or something else).

You might also find it easier to declare a global `dbinfo` instead of a `dbinfo *`, depending on the usage of your program. The more data you can move out of dynamic runtime allocation, the better.